# Selecionar múltiplas linhas de um data.frame, a partir dos maiores valores R

Tags: r, data, dplyr

Tenho o seguinte data.frame em R:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10,10,2,3,4,8,8,8),
                 y = c(5,4,6,7,8,3,2,4))
df
   x y
1 10 5
2 10 4
3  2 6
4  3 7
5  4 8
6  8 3
7  8 2
8  8 4
```

**Primeiro ponto**: Gostaria de obter todas a linhas que contém os 5 maiores valores da coluna `x`, podendo repetir.

Exemplo:

Os cinco maiores da coluna `x` são: `10, 10, 8, 8, 8.`

Consigo obter com o seguinte código:

```
rev(sort(df$x))[1:5]
[1] 10 10  8  8  8
```

Mas eu gostaria de pegar toda a linha, não somente os valores da coluna `x`. Portanto, o resultado que desejo é:

```
1 10 5
2 10 4
6  8 3
7  8 2
8  8 4
```

E não:

```
> [1] 10 10  8  8  8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  top_n(x, n=5)
   x y
1 10 5
2 10 4
3  8 3
4  8 2
5  8 4
```

Usando `order`, uma das funções padrão do `R`:

```
df[order(df$x, decreasing=TRUE), ][1:5, ]
   x y
1 10 5
2 10 4
6  8 3
7  8 2
8  8 4
```

Perceba que a solução com `dplyr` cria um output sem relação com o data frame antigo, enquanto a solução com `order` te informa quais linhas do data frame original foram mantidas nesta seleção atual.

Comment: Se eu quisesse tirar a repetições? No caso, os valores das linhas eram 10,8,4,3,2. Como seria?

Comment: Quero pegar todas as linhas que contém na coluna "X"o 10,8,4,3,2.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar, como fazer no `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[order(x, decreasing = T),][1:5,]
    x y
1: 10 5
2: 10 4
3:  8 3
4:  8 2
5:  8 4
```

Para remover duplicados na coluna `x`, ordenar por `x` e pegar os 5 primeiros:

```
df[!duplicated(x),][order(x, decreasing = T), ][1:5, ]
```

Comment: Show! completei o código com:

b <- df[!duplicated(x),][order(x, decreasing = T), ][1:5, ]

df[which(df$x %in% b),]